# Which valuation satisfy the following formulas?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working on the propositional logic and got stuck at the following exercice:

Which valuations $v : \{p_1, \dots, p_n\} \to \{0, 1\}$ satisfy the following formulas $A:=(p_1 \to p_2)∧(p_2  \to p_3)∧ \cdots ∧(p_{n−1} \to p_n)$?

I tried to compute the truth table but I still don't see the general case.. Can someone please help me out? Many thanks!

Comment: Either all $p_i$ must be True or all False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formula in the form $$\phi_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\phi_n$$ is true if and only if all $\phi_j$ are true (by definition of the "and" $\wedge$). In your case, $$\phi_j=p_j\rightarrow p_{j+1}$$ An implication $\phi\rightarrow\psi$ is true in three cases: $$0\rightarrow0\qquad0\rightarrow1\qquad1\rightarrow1$$
so if you evaluate $v(p_j)=0$, then $v(p_{j+1})$ can be any value and $\phi_j$ would be true. If you evaluate $v(p_j)=1$, then $v(p_{j+1})$ must be $1$.

So the only valuations $v$ that satisfy $A$ are those *monotone*, that is, $$v(p_j)\leqslant v(p_{j+1})$$ for example, $v(p_1)=\cdots=v(p_n)=1,0$, like in the comment, but also $v(p_1)=0$ and $v(p_2)=\cdots=v(p_n)=1$ is correct (because then $\phi_1$ is false implies true, which is true, and all the other $\phi_j$ are true implies true, which is true as well)

Comment: Thanks! There ist just a small typo in your case distinction, 0 should be send to 0 in the first case

Comment: You're right, I'll edit that